# Use wildcards to find all excluded matching strings

Tags: vba, ms-word, full-text-search, wildcard

I am trying to improve a VBA macro that I have used with some success. What the macro is intended to do is search a Word document find and highlight specific text strings that do NOT match the given find criteria.

This macro works quite well when the search results are whole numbers. But when a leading zero is involved it will not find and highlight.

```
Sub Find_Highlight_Height()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    'Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
    '  .Text = "Height {1,}-[!0]{1,}*mm"
      .Text = "Height {1,}-[!0]*(mm)>"
      With .Replacement
        .Text = "^&"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
      End With
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

By this I mean the following:
A text string that I do not want to match. "Height -0mm" (yes there is one or more spaces between the "t" and "-")

So all other strings I want to match (for a few examples) "Height -1mm", "Height -1.0mm", "Height -10.5mm", and "Height -0.5mm".

The above wildcard `.Text = "Height {1,}-[!0]*(mm)>"` works as expected for all results except the one with the leading zero (last one). I have tried so many combinations of the wildcard string I have lost count

What am I missing? And is there a better way to go about this "inverse find" and highlight?

Comment: How about `"Height {1,}-[0-9.]*(mm)>"`

Comment: ...or without the `*` even

Comment: Tim, It has to be only an excluded zero (want all results but the 0mm) to be highlighted . Looks like what is happening is that it sees the exclusion [!0] and this disregards the rest of the pattern *(mm)>

Comment: That pattern worked for me with the examples you provided.  It would also detect (eg) `Height -0.0.1mm` though.  Not having a "zero or one instance" flag is a bit of a problem.  EDIT - I only just saw you explicitly didn't want to match `Height -0mm`

Comment: Not sure what it is, but the period/dot after the exclusion [!0] seems to make the find function disregard the rest of the pattern, so it doesn't flag the result.

Comment: Without a more fully-functional wildcard system I guess you're stuck with running the find/replace in a loop and checking each hit to see if it needs to be highlighted.

Comment: Try "(Height)( {1,})(-)([0-9]{1,})(.)([0-9m]{1,})".  If you need units other than mm then add the appropriate characters to the [0-9m]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Freeflow, I was able to include this to catch the decimal point finds. See working code below

I ended up having to loop thru the find twice. The first time to catch everything that wasn't "Height -0mm" (95% of the results). Then the second time to catch the remaining results that contained a decimal point.

```
' Use to search and highlight all matching from the phrase ".Text =" line below
'
' Explane the ".Text = "Height {1,}-[!0]{1,}" wildcard pattern match
' Height - (just the begining text string to search for)
' [!0] (telling to find anything except the number zero)
' {1,} ( telling the find that there may be one or more in a row)

Sub Find_Highlight_Height()

Dim loopTimes As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
'Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed

' Looping thru twice so can capture find's with and without decimal points
' Discovered an issue with VBA in that the decimal point halts the find pattern when present
' right after a exclude "!" pattern element this case the "[!0]"
For loopTimes = 1 To 2

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting

    If loopTimes = 1 Then
       .Text = "Height {1,}-[!0]{1,}*mm" 'Works when decimal point is NOT present
    Else
        .Text = "(Height)( {1,})(-)([0-9]{1,})(.)([0-9m]{1,})" 'Works when decimal is present
    End If

    With .Replacement
        .Text = "^&"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
    End With
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

Next loopTimes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am still baffeled at why VBA stops the wildcard pattern when a decimal follows an exclusion in the pattern.